# Angular slickgrid multiselect editor field needs to remove the focus while pressing ok button without changing data

Tags: angular, angular-slickgrid

I am using angular slickgrid to display my data and also for inline editing data. In table inline edit working fine but some exceptional cases are present. For multiselect editor the cell change callback not called while i am pressing ok button without changing the multiselect value its fine. but the edit view still maintaining the focus state. Any solution to remove the focus in the editor.

---

**Current Behavior**

Multiselect editor maintaining the focus while pressing ok button without changing data.

[image]

---

**Expected Behavior**

Multiselect editor field needs to remove the focus while pressing ok button without changing data.

---

Here i shared my code snippet for your reference

**Html**

```
<angular-slickgrid gridId="{{gridId}}" [columnDefinitions]="columnDefinitions" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    [dataset]="filteredResultList" (sgOnClick)="onGridItemClick($event)"
    (onAngularGridCreated)="angularGridReady($event)"
    (sgOnCellChange)="onCellChanged($event.detail.eventData, $event.detail.args)">
</angular-slickgrid>
```

---

**Grid options**

```
public gridOptions: GridOption = {
    enableAutoResize: true,
    autoEdit: false,
    autoCommitEdit: true,
    enableCellNavigation: true,
    editable: true,
    enableSorting: true,
    enableFiltering: true,
    i18n: this.translateService,
    enableExcelExport: true,
    enableExport: true,
    gridMenu: {
        hideExportExcelCommand: true,
        hideExportCsvCommand: true,
        customItems: [{
            command: "cspfm-excel-export",
            titleKey: "EXPORT_TO_EXCEL",
            iconCssClass: "fa fa-file-excel-o",
            action: (event, callbackArgs) => {
                this.excelExport(event, callbackArgs)
            }
        },
        {
            command: "cspfm-csv-export",
            titleKey: "EXPORT_TO_CSV",
            iconCssClass: "fa fa-download",
            action: (event, callbackArgs) => {
                this.excelExport(event, callbackArgs)
            }
        }
        ],
    },
    enableAutoTooltip: true,
    autoTooltipOptions: {
        enableForCells: true,
        enableForHeaderCells: true,
        maxToolTipLength: 1000
    },
    autoResize: {
        containerId: this.gridContainerId,
        calculateAvailableSizeBy: 'container'
    },
    exportOptions: {
        exportWithFormatter: true
    },
    excelExportOptions: {
        exportWithFormatter: true,
    },
    headerMenu: {
        hideColumnHideCommand: true
    },
    enableTranslate: true,
    presets: {
        sorters: [{
            columnId: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_name']['prop'],
            direction: 'ASC'
        }],
    }
};
```

---

**Table column info**

```
public tableColumnInfo = {
    "pfm187413": {
        "pfm187413_name": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.name",
            "fieldName": "name",
            "prop": "name",
            "fieldType": "TEXT",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": "",
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_student": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.student",
            "fieldName": "student",
            "prop": "student",
            "fieldType": "TEXT",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": "",
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_about": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.about",
            "fieldName": "about",
            "prop": "about",
            "fieldType": "TEXTAREA",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": "",
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_qualification": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.qualification",
            "fieldName": "qualification",
            "prop": "qualification",
            "fieldType": "DROPDOWN",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": {
                "ma": "MA",
                "ba": "BA",
                "bt": "BTECH",
                "mca": "MCA"
            },
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_dateofbirth": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.dateofbirth",
            "fieldName": "dateofbirth",
            "prop": "dateofbirth",
            "fieldType": "DATE",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": this.appUtilityConfig.userDateFormat,
            "mappingDetails": "",
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_starttime": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.starttime",
            "fieldName": "starttime",
            "prop": "starttime",
            "fieldType": "TIMESTAMP",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": this.appUtilityConfig.userDateTimeFormat,
            "mappingDetails": "",
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_gender": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.gender",
            "fieldName": "gender",
            "prop": "gender",
            "fieldType": "RADIO",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": {
                "m": "Male",
                "f": "Female"
            },
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_favourites": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.favourites",
            "fieldName": "favourites",
            "prop": "favourites",
            "fieldType": "MULTISELECT",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": {
                "ds": "Dosa",
                "idli": "Idly",
                "ps": "Pasta",
                "sl": "Salad"
            },
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_sports": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.sports",
            "fieldName": "sports",
            "prop": "sports",
            "fieldType": "CHECKBOX",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": {
                "ck": "Cricket",
                "ft": "Football",
                "rg": "Rugby"
            },
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_servicecost": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.servicecost",
            "fieldName": "servicecost",
            "prop": "servicecost",
            "fieldType": "CURRENCY",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": "",
            "currencyDetails": {
                "currencyCode": "$",
                "display": true,
                "digitsInfo": "1.2-2",
                "locale": "ms-BN"
            }
        },
        "pfm187413_cgapercent": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.cgapercent",
            "fieldName": "cgapercent",
            "prop": "cgapercent",
            "fieldType": "DECIMAL",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": "",
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_points": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.points",
            "fieldName": "points",
            "prop": "points",
            "fieldType": "NUMBER",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": "",
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_url": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.url",
            "fieldName": "url",
            "prop": "url",
            "fieldType": "URL",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": "",
            "currencyDetails": ""
        },
        "pfm187413_isactive": {
            "label": "LTFieldTrackSingleGLISTVA_WEB_Grid_with_List.Element.fieldtracksinglejuy.isactive",
            "fieldName": "isactive",
            "prop": "isactive",
            "fieldType": "BOOLEAN",
            "child": "",
            "dateFormat": "",
            "mappingDetails": "",
            "currencyDetails": ""
        }
    }
};
```

---

**Column definitions**

```
public columnDefinitions: Array<Column> = [{
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_name']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_name']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_name']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.string,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,

    filterable: true,
    filter: {


        model: Filters.compoundInput
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.longText,
        required: true
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_name']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_student']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_student']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_student']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.string,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,

    filterable: true,
    filter: {


        model: Filters.compoundInput
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.longText,
        required: true
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_student']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_about']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_about']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_about']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.string,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,

    filterable: true,
    filter: {


        model: Filters.compoundInput
    },

    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_about']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_qualification']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_qualification']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_qualification']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.string,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    queryField: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_qualification']['prop'] + appConstant['customFieldSuffix']['slickgrid'],
    filterable: true,
    filter: {
        collection: this.getLabelValue(this.qualification_371375),

        model: Filters.multipleSelect
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.singleSelect,
        collection: this.getKeyValue(this.qualification_371375),
        required: true
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_qualification']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_dateofbirth']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_dateofbirth']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_dateofbirth']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.date,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    queryField: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_dateofbirth']['prop'] + appConstant['customFieldSuffix']['slickgrid'],
    filterable: true,
    filter: {

        operator: OperatorType.rangeInclusive,
        model: Filters.compoundDate
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.date,
        required: true,
        editorOptions:
            {
                onReady: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
                    const flatpickrYearElement = instance.currentYearElement;

                    const children = flatpickrYearElement.parentElement.children;
                    for (let i in children) {
                        if (children.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            children[i].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }

                    const yearSelect = document.createElement('select');
                    var minDate = new Date();
                    minDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    minDate.setFullYear(minDate.getFullYear() - 100);
                    var maxDate = new Date();
                    maxDate.setHours(23, 59, 58, 999);
                    maxDate.setFullYear(maxDate.getFullYear() + 50);
                    instance.config._minDate = minDate;
                    instance.config._maxDate = maxDate;
                    const minYear = new Date(instance.config._minDate).getFullYear();
                    const maxYear = new Date(instance.config._maxDate).getFullYear();

                    for (let i = minYear; i <= maxYear; i++) {
                        const option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.value = '' + i;
                        option.text = '' + i;
                        yearSelect.appendChild(option);
                    }
                    yearSelect.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                        flatpickrYearElement.value = event.target['value'];
                        instance.changeYear(parseInt(event.target['value']));
                    });

                    yearSelect.className = 'flatpickr-monthDropdown-months';
                    yearSelect.id = 'flatpickr-custom-year-select';
                    yearSelect.value = instance.currentYearElement.value;

                    flatpickrYearElement.parentElement.appendChild(yearSelect);
                },
                onMonthChange: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
                    document.getElementById('flatpickr-custom-year-select')['value'] = '' + instance.currentYear;
                }
            } as FlatpickrOption
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_dateofbirth']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_starttime']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_starttime']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_starttime']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.dateTime,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    queryField: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_starttime']['prop'] + appConstant['customFieldSuffix']['slickgrid'],
    filterable: true,
    filter: {

        operator: OperatorType.rangeInclusive,
        model: Filters.compoundDate
    },

    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_starttime']
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.date,
        required: true,
        editorOptions:
            {
                onReady: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
                    const flatpickrYearElement = instance.currentYearElement;

                    const children = flatpickrYearElement.parentElement.children;
                    for (let i in children) {
                        if (children.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                            children[i].style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }

                    const yearSelect = document.createElement('select');
                    var minDate = new Date();
                    minDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
                    minDate.setFullYear(minDate.getFullYear() - 100);
                    var maxDate = new Date();
                    maxDate.setHours(23, 59, 58, 999);
                    maxDate.setFullYear(maxDate.getFullYear() + 50);
                    instance.config._minDate = minDate;
                    instance.config._maxDate = maxDate;
                    const minYear = new Date(instance.config._minDate).getFullYear();
                    const maxYear = new Date(instance.config._maxDate).getFullYear();

                    for (let i = minYear; i <= maxYear; i++) {
                        const option = document.createElement('option');
                        option.value = '' + i;
                        option.text = '' + i;
                        yearSelect.appendChild(option);
                    }
                    yearSelect.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
                        flatpickrYearElement.value = event.target['value'];
                        instance.changeYear(parseInt(event.target['value']));
                    });

                    yearSelect.className = 'flatpickr-monthDropdown-months';
                    yearSelect.id = 'flatpickr-custom-year-select';
                    yearSelect.value = instance.currentYearElement.value;

                    flatpickrYearElement.parentElement.appendChild(yearSelect);
                },
                onMonthChange: (selectedDates, dateStr, instance) => {
                    document.getElementById('flatpickr-custom-year-select')['value'] = '' + instance.currentYear;
                }
            } as FlatpickrOption
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_gender']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_gender']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_gender']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.string,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    queryField: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_gender']['prop'] + appConstant['customFieldSuffix']['slickgrid'],
    filterable: true,
    filter: {
        collection: this.getLabelValue(this.gender_371378),

        model: Filters.multipleSelect
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.singleSelect,
        collection: this.getKeyValue(this.gender_371378),
        required: true
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_gender']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_favourites']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_favourites']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_favourites']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.string,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    queryField: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_favourites']['prop'] + appConstant['customFieldSuffix']['slickgrid'],
    filterable: true,
    filter: {
        collection: this.getLabelValue(this.favourites_371379),
        operator: OperatorType.inContains,
        model: Filters.multipleSelect
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.multipleSelect,
        collection: this.getKeyValue(this.favourites_371379)
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_favourites']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_sports']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_sports']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_sports']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.string,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    queryField: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_sports']['prop'] + appConstant['customFieldSuffix']['slickgrid'],
    filterable: true,
    filter: {
        collection: this.getLabelValue(this.sports_371380),
        operator: OperatorType.inContains,
        model: Filters.multipleSelect
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.multipleSelect,
        collection: this.getKeyValue(this.sports_371380),
        operator: OperatorType.inContains
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_sports']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_servicecost']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_servicecost']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_servicecost']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.number,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,

    filterable: true,
    filter: {


        model: Filters.compoundInputNumber
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.float,
        params: {
            decimalPlaces: 2
        },
        required: true
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_servicecost']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_cgapercent']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_cgapercent']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_cgapercent']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.number,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,

    filterable: true,
    filter: {
        model: Filters.compoundInputNumber
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_cgapercent']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_points']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_points']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_points']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.number,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    filterable: true,
    filter: {
        model: Filters.compoundInputNumber
    },
    editor: {
        model: cspfmCustomEditor,
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_points']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_url']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_url']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_url']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.string,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    filterable: true,
    filter: {
        model: Filters.compoundInput
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.longText,
        required: true
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_url']
    }
}, {
    id: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_isactive']['prop'],
    nameKey: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_isactive']['label'],
    field: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_isactive']['prop'],
    sortable: true,
    type: FieldType.string,
    exportCustomFormatter: CspfmDataFormatter,
    minWidth: this.columnMinWidth,
    formatter: CspfmDataFormatter,

    filterable: true,
    filter: {
        collection: this.getLabelValue({
            true: "true",
            false: "false"
        }),

        model: Filters.multipleSelect
    },
    editor: {
        model: Editors.checkbox,
        collection: [{
            value: true,
            label: 'True'
        },
        {
            valued: false,
            label: 'False'
        }
        ]
    },
    params: {
        pipe: this.cspfmDataDisplay,
        fieldInfo: this.tableColumnInfo['pfm187413']['pfm187413_isactive']
    }
}];
```

---

**Behavior of angular slickgrid sample project**

[image]

---

**Software Version**

Angular : 7.3.5

Angular-Slickgrid : 2.19.0

TypeScript : 3.1.6

Operating System : Windows 10

Node : 10.16.3

NPM : 6.9.0

Answer (score 0):

You need the Grid Option `autoCommitEdit: true` to commit the change right away, which will push the change, close the editor and so lose focus from it. Doing that will also trigger an `onCellChange` event right away (while having `autoCommitEdit: false` won't trigger until you tab away or blur away).

The default is `autoCommitEdit: false` which has the behavior that you mentioned and is normal. You need to tab away or focus on another cell. I personally always use `autoCommitEdit: true` to avoid such behavior. The behavior you mentioned is considered "As Per Designed" and won't change.

Also note that using `autoCommitEdit: false` on a Text Editor will go down to the next available row while `autoCommitEdit: true` will simply commit only the current cell and not open any other editor. That is again a behavior that I don't really like but some user might.

So the quick answer is use `autoCommitEdit: true`

NOTE

Please don't override the `onClose` method of the Select Editor, if you are then you are completely overriding the lib with its own `onClose` usage [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/editors/selectEditor.ts#L119). The `autoCommitEdit` is only used and effective within the `onClose` (when that triggers it calls the internal code [save](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/editors/selectEditor.ts#L419) which checks the `autoCommitEdit` flag at that time) and so if you are overriding the `onClose` then this flag as no effect whatsoever.

EDIT 1

I cannot replicate your issue on the demo... actually that is no longer true, I misunderstood the original question. The behavior that is problematic and is asked in the question is from SlickGrid (core lib)

EDIT 2

You can probably fix your problem by adding an event to the `body` and once click then run the Editors commit. Something like

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // auto-commit any opened editor, that will close the editor and commit the changes
  if (this.grid.getEditorLock()) {
    this.grid.getEditorLock().commitCurrentEdit();
  }
});
```

[image: auto-commit]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already enabled autoCommitEdit property in gridoption. With autoCommitEdit: true, editor lose the focus. But exceptional case is without changing the value, editor didn't lose the focus while pressing ok button or outside click.

Comment: For the above mentioned case, I studied little bit core slickgird lib and have done a work around by calling the core slickgrid method. In core slickgrid lib the cell focus removed without value change condition. If value changed existing process flow working fine. 

`editorOptions: { onClose: () => { if (this.gridObj) { this.gridObj.getEditorLock().commitCurrentEdit(); } } }`

Kindly advise and confirm, is there any impact if i am using above code.

Comment: The `autoCommitEdit` flag was created specifically for Angular-Slickgrid and what you're doing is exactly what Angular-Slickgrid does in each filter as can be seen on this [line](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/editors/selectEditor.ts#L423), so you're basically doing the exact same thing and I'm not sure why you'd want to do that and not use the flag `autoCommitEdit` unless you want just that Editor to follow this behavior and not the other Editors but even then I'm not sure why you'll want to do that

Comment: Please check my question. I already enabled `autoCommitEdit` property in grid options. But it working while changing the values, but without changing value the editor focus not removed. So that I tried this code. If any solution present to remove the editor focus in angular slickgrid, please share with me. I am very glad to use that solution.

Comment: it works correctly in the [Example - Editors](https://ghiscoding.github.io/Angular-Slickgrid/#/editor) when the "Auto Commit Edit" checkbox is ticked, so I can't replicate your issue... unless you're overriding the `onClose` which I think you are, Angular-Slickgrid calls the `save()` internally [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/editors/selectEditor.ts#L119) which then uses the `autoCommitEdit` but if you're overriding the `onClose` then you are bypassing the lib and completely igoring the `autoCommitEdit`.. so don't do that

Comment: I referred your sample and it having the same issue which I described earlier. **I have updated the screen recorder clip of your sample** in the question section. Please have a look on it. 

I feel that, it is not good from the user perspective. This is the reason I want to defocus the column when I am not doing any changes in the all type column values. So I am planning to defocus when the window is closed.

Comment: The similar scenario I am facing in flatpicker component. I need consolidated changes. I don't want separate changes such as date, time, AM/PM. I am looking for something like OK button at the bottom of the flatpicker window to get the consolidated final changes to perform further. Similarly i have a plan to change all type editor defocus while clicking outside of editor.

**Note: I tried all this case with auto-commit enabled state only.**

This is feasible when it can be done with core lib. Other than this, do you have any solution, it will be welcome.

Comment: What you described is a SlickGrid behavior, you can replicate it in the core lib [Example Editor](https://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example3-editing.html) on the columns "% Complete", "Start" and "Finish", this has been there since the beginning. May I remind you this is an Open Source project, you should seriously think about contributing

Comment: Just click outside of editor without changing values or ok button click. Need to remove the focus. That is my requirements.

Comment: For that reason only i am trying to handle all editor works in onclose callback. This will not affect the auto commit features. Because auto commit property is always enabled in my application.

Comment: I have helped you a lot with all the issues and SO questions you've opened in the past, I would greatly appreciate if you can consider contributing to the lib with a possible fix. This would help all the community using the lib, that is what the Open Source is all about, so please consider contributing.

Comment: I edited my answer with another possible trick that you can try, it might work

Comment: Thanks for your information, i tried this in onClose callback. Already i shared the code in comment section [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63306220/angular-slickgrid-multiselect-editor-field-needs-to-remove-the-focus-while-press/63404270?noredirect=1#comment112128282_63404270). If i found any proper solution means i will contribute to slickgrid lib